# How to change style to input in a React hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have validation that displays an error message, how to make the input border red when the form is incorrectly filled?

```
<div className={styles["form-group"]}>
    <label>
        Temat
    </label>
    <input
        {...register("temat", { required: ErrorType.REQUIRED })}
        className={styles.input}
    />
    <p className={styles.invalid}>{errors?.temat?.message}</p>
</div>
```

How will I use it:

```
style={{ border: errors.temat?.message ? '1px solid red' : '' }}
```

The input turns red after clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

**A: You have to use conditional classes**

```
className={ errors?.myInput?.message ? styles["error"] : "no-error" }
```

[image: Clean form] [image: Error with border]

in this example I am using [scss modules](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-sass-and-css-modules-with-create-react-app-83fa8b805e5e) so i'll type the classNames as follow `styles["myClassName"]`

```
<input
    
    id="accountReference"
    
    className={
        errors?.accountReference?.message ? styles["error"] : "no-error"
    }
    
    {...register("accountReference", {
    
        required: "Account reference is required",
    
    })}
    
/>
```

**scss**

```scss
input {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: var(--100);
    border: 2px solid var(--300);
    padding: 8px 12px;
    &.error {
        border: 2px solid var(--error);
    }
}
```

or you could do it in **css**

```css
input {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
input.error {
        border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
const {formState: { errors }} = useForm();

<Input
  style={errors.yourinputID && { border: "2px solid red" }}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change mode on useForm. It works for me.

```
useForm({
  mode: 'onChange',
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a className for errors on the input element:

```
<div className={styles["form-group"]}>
  <label>
    Temat
  </label>
  <input
  {...register("temat", { required: ErrorType.REQUIRED })}
  className={`${styles.input} ${styles.errors}`}
  />
  <p className={styles.invalid}>{errors?.temat?.message}</p>
</div>
```

or look use a library like [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)